# Powershell replaces &quot with "

Tags: xml, powershell

In below snippets

```
<M>
    &lt;remove name=&quot;Session&quot; /&gt;
</M>
```

```
$filePath = "a.xml"
$s = [xml](Get-Content $filePath)
$s.Save($filePath)
```

How do I retain the &quot as is? Right this is how the file looks after the script

```
<M>
        &lt;remove name="Session" /&gt;
</M>
```

I cannot modify the XML format, as it is part of a different system.

Comment: From XML point-of-view, `"` and `&quot;` in this context are equivalent.

Comment: That part inside the root node is supposed to be an XML string. think that will change some more stuff. updated the snippet

Comment: The strings are still equivalent.

Comment: I understand that you cannot modify the XML, but just to spell the proper solution out: for your input XML to behave the way you expect with a standards-compliant XML parser, the `&` chars. would have to be escaped as `&amp;`. That is, `&lt;remove name=&quot;Session&quot; /&gt;` would have to be `&amp;lt;remove name=&amp;quot;Session&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;`

Comment: So if the `&quot;` turning into literal `"` is something you truly need to prevent, neither of the built-in .NET  XML parsers - `System.Xml.XmlDocument` and `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` -
will help you. In a pinch, you could try regex-based post-processing, but that is generally brittle and would have to rely on identifying relevant patterns to prevent false positives.
Are there such patterns?

Answer (score 1):

- PowerShell is just the messenger here, **you're seeing the behavior of the [`[xml]`([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)) .NET class**.<sup>[1]</sup>
- In *most* cases<sup>[2]</sup> - such as in your example - **XML does *not* require `"` characters to be escaped as `&quot;`**.

  - However, **the two representations - `"` as-is vs. `&quot;` - are *equivalent* and can be used *interchangeably* in XML text**.
  - Therefore, as long as you're dealing with a standards-compliant XML parser, ***it should not matter* which of the two representations is used in a given document**.
- While the `[xml]` class offers *some* control over preserving the text format of the original (text) document - notably preserving *insignificant* whitespace - you get *no* control over preservation of character entity references in the input text:

  - In fact, by the time you have *loaded* (parsed) the XML text, the information is already *lost*, and the class simply escapes those characters that need it *on demand* when *saving* the in-memory document representation back to a file via the `.Save()` method or converting it to an XML *string* via its `.OuterXml` property.
  - A **simplified example**:

    ```bash
    # -> <foo>3" of snow &amp; more</foo>
    ([xml] '<foo>3&quot; of snow &amp; more</foo>').OuterXml
    ```

    - *In memory*, `&quot;` became literal `"` and `&amp;` became literal `&` (you can see this if you replace `.OuterXml` with `.foo` above, to output the *string content* of the `<foo>` element, which yields verbatim `3" of snow & more`).
    - On *serialization* (to a *string* in this case, via `.OuterXml`), the literal `"` was kept as-is - because it does *not* require escaping - whereas the literal `&` - which *does* require escaping - became `&amp;` a character entity reference.

---

<sup>[1] Note that the other XML parser that comes with .NET, [`System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.Linq.XDocument), exhibits the same behavior.</sup>

<sup>[2] Escaping is only needed if you need to *embed* `"` characters *inside a double-quoted attribute value*; e.g.

`<foo stage-name="Nat &quot;King&quot; Cole" />` in order to make the `stage-name` attribute contain verbatim `Nat "King" Cole`.</sup>

Answer (score -2):

I did this and it worked for me. might be the only way you can get it to work.  This is however a very simple answer.

```
$xmlString = "<M> &quot; </M>"

#save xml string to $s
$s = [xml]$xmlString

#convert " to &quot"
$s.M = $s.M.Replace('"', '&quot;')

Write-Host $s.M
```

rewriting my answer since i was given more information.  If that is the case the best course of action is to replace the & in `&quot;` to `&amp;quot;`

```
$filePath = "a.xml"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $filePath)

# Replace &quot; with &amp;quot;
foreach ($node in $xml.SelectNodes("//*[contains(text(), '&quot;')]")) {
    $node.InnerXml = $node.InnerXml -replace '&quot;', '&amp;quot;'
}

$xml.Save($filePath)
```

give that a shot and let me know if that helps.

Comment: This would break with all but the simplest input XML. Consider what happens with `<M name="foo"> &quot;</M>`, for instance.

Comment: yeah I should clarify that `"` and `&quot` are functionally equivalent.  But to be fair he asked with a very simple input about XML and I just assumed he was asking more as a hypothetical than asking for something functional.  otherwise he would have added something more complex.

Comment: I suggest adding important clarifications like that directly to the answer. I don't think it's fair to assume that the question was hypothetical, as evidenced by the statement "I cannot modify the XML format, as it is part of a different system" in the question. Rather, it looks like a simplified example was used to illustrate the problem with the real XML (whose specifics aren't important).

Comment: Correct. the real xml is ~2000 lines long, with a lot of other quotes that cannot be replaced.

Comment: rjv could you provide a more complex snippet of the xml?

Comment: rewrote my answer since i was given more context.